# How does the correlation statistic parameter affect the cost of index scan?

Tags: postgresql, index

I have the table `customers` having `customerid SERIAL` as a primary key. Initially I had the following statistic for that column:

```
  attname   n_distinct    correlation
customerid       -1         -0.393365
```

The following query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerid < 10
```

produced the following analyzed plan:

```
Index Scan using customers_pkey on customers  (cost=0.00..35.46 rows=9 width=268) (actual time=0.003..0.010 rows=9 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (customerid < 10)
Total runtime: 0.029 ms
```

Note, that the cost to get all rows is `35.46`. Now, I ran

```
CLUSTER customers USING customers_pkey;
ANALYZE;
```

and the `correlation` became equals to `1`. After running the query once again I got the following analyzed plan:

```
Index Scan using customers_pkey on customers  (cost=0.00..8.41 rows=9 width=268) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=9 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (customerid < 10)
Total runtime: 0.024 ms
```

Note that the cost is decreased more than 4 times (`8.41` now). My question is how exactly the cost of `ranged index scan` depends on the correlation? How is it computed? It would be good if you pointed out to some references to the postgresql documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details you want will not be found in the documentation, but rather in the source code.  In particular, `src/backend/optimizer/path/costsize.c` in the function `cost_index`.

It computes `min_IO_cost` based on the assumption the table is correlated, `max_IO_cost` based on the assumption it is uncorrelated, and then interpolates between them based on the correlation.

Comment: In short, the more correlation parameter, the less cost of the ranged index scan, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  (Also an equality scan when there are many equal keys.)